# Issues with creating subdomain running on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I have a static webpage, `example.com`, that is working fine and hosted on AWS S3 with Route53 connecting the `A` and `NS` record sets to my GoDaddy DNS.

I want to create `sub.example.com` that points to a dynamical page that will be hosted on my EC2 instance. I have my EC2 associated with an Elastic IP, whose public address is `12.12.12.12`. I set up Route53 by creating a separate hosted zone for `sub.example.com` with 3 record sets:

- An `A` record set named `sub.example.com` with the value `12.12.12.12`.
- An `NS` record set with values `NS-1.org`, `NS-2.org`,`NS-3.org`, and `NS-4.org`.
- AWS seems to have generated an `SOA` record set, with values `ns-1.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 0002 003 0000004 00005`

All record sets are named `sub.example.com`. In my GoDaddy account, under `DNS Zone File`, I added the following:

- `A` record set - name `sub` pointing to `12.12.12.12`
- 4 `NS` records - name `sub` pointing to `NS-1.org`, `NS-2.org`,`NS-3.org`, and `NS-4.org`.

Am I missing something? My server is not running yet, I just want to verify that my DNS settings are ready first.

While `dig example.com NS` works, I tested `sub.example.com` with command `dig sub.example.com NS` and it failed:

```
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/lucas$ dig sub.example.com NS

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> sub.example.com NS
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 44939
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1280
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;sub.example.com.       IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.        900 IN  SOA ns-5.net. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 0002 003 0000004 00005

;; Query time: 79 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Thu May 15 13:07:40 PDT 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 128
```

Interestingly, in the `AUTHORITY SECTION`, the `SOA` points to `ns-5.net`, which is under my `NS` set for the `example.com` hosted zone, NOT my `sub.example.com` zone. Any suggestions?

I also queried WHOIS for `sub.example.com`:

```
Domain Name: EXAMPLE.COM
Registrar: GODADDY.COM, LLC
Whois Server: whois.godaddy.com
Referral URL: http://registrar.godaddy.com
Name Server: NS-5.ORG
Name Server: NS-6.ORG
Name Server: NS-7.ORG
Name Server: NS-8.ORG
Status: clientDeleteProhibited
Status: clientRenewProhibited
Status: clientTransferProhibited
Status: clientUpdateProhibited
Updated Date: 30-jun-2014
Creation Date: 30-jun-2013
Expiration Date: 30-jun-2015
```

It indicates that my `NS` records are pointing to the name servers for `example.com` and not `sub.example.com`.

Am I missing something, or am I doing too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `NS` records for `sub.example.com`. You only need `NS` records for your domain, `example.com`. The `A` record is enough for `sub.example.com`.

Comment: You were right, just the `A` record was enough. Since my server was not running, I was also able to verify that the correct IP was connected through the WHOIS website.